# AUC/C-index confidence interval estimate

Tags: estimation, auc, concordance

Is there a way to compute an estimate of the AUC/C-index confidence interval, simply by using a mean AUC/C-index and sample size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments to your question and other answer, if there is no information such as the variance available (and just the estimate, which I assume you refer to with the 'mean'), AFAIK it is not possible to deduce the necessary information to calculate a confidence interval.

If you however have access to slightly more information (i.e. the amount of cases and total sample size), you could calculate [Hanley's variance of the c-index](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=7063747) as estimate for the variance. This is used in meta-analyses of prognostic research (in the biomedical field), when variance or confidence intervals are not given, but the information is needed to pool multiple c-indices.

Hanley variance ($H.var$): if $c$ is the c-index you've found, $N$ is total sample size and $n_1$ resembles the amount of cases, variance is calculated like so:

Take 
$Q1=c/(2-c)$; and $Q2=(2*(c^2))/(1+c)$

Then
$H.var = (c*(1-c)+(n_1-1)*(Q1-(c^2))+(N-n_1-1)*(Q2- c^2))/(n_1*(N-n_1))$

So now you have variance and need to assume a distribution for the c-index which is plausible to find a confidence interval. I've been taught not to assume a normal distribution on the c-index scale, because the c-index is bounded by $[0.5,1]$ (or $[0,1]$ for that matter, but still the bounds exist). Especially when the c-index is close to these bounds a normal distribution is far off. The alternative is to transform everything to the logit scale (which transforms a $[0,1]$ bounded value to a $<-Inf,Inf>$ value), and then calculate a $1-α$% confidence interval using a normal distribution:

$c.logit=log(c/(1-c))$; and $c.var.logit=H.var/((c*(1-c))^{2})$

Then:
$CI =e^{c.logit±z_α*c.var.logit} / (1+ e^{c.logit±z_α*c.var.logit})$

Comment: Great thanks a lot! Do you happen to have a paper which supports the logit calculation at the end (it seems obvious that this is correct, but a published paper always helps ;))

Comment: @HéctorvandenBoorn My apologies, I now see I've made a mistake in the backcalculation from the logit scale to the original c-index scale. I've edited the final formula accordingly

Answer (score -1):

If you have AUC calculated for multiple "subjects" or samples and want to estimate the precision of the mean AUC, you can use a simple parametric confidence interval for the mean:

$$CI=M \pm SE_M*t_{crit}=M \pm \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}*t_{crit}$$

where $M$ is the mean, $s$ is the standard deviation, $n$ is the number of subjects, and $t_{crit}$ is the critical $t$ value with $n-1$ degrees of freedom (asymptotically approaches 1.96).

**Edit:** A better solution would be to use bootstrapped confidence intervals, but that is more complicated than simply using the mean and sample size. See comments.

Comment: If so, this is news to me. What mean are you referring to & what SE? The AUC is a proportion bounded by [.5, 1]. This doesn't seem like it would be the right answer, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Why AUC is assumed t-distributed?

Comment: @gung AUC can be lower than 0.5.

Comment: A better solution would be to use bootstrapped confidence intervals, but the question asked for a solution using a simple mean and sample size.

Comment: @gung The mean is referencing a distribution of AUCs calculated on multiple subjects, separately. I'm not suggesting using this formula for a single subject.

Comment: @SmallChess, yes, but only if the model is badly mis-specified. I'm not assuming that by default.

Comment: But I don't know what the standard deviation is; I only know the mean and sample size and the fact that it is a AUC (theoretically between 0 and 1 but in practice between 0.5 and 1)

Comment: If you only have a mean and sample size, you cannot compute a confidence interval. If you have the raw data, you have many options but without a measure of variability at least, you are very limited.